# Docker compose images rebuild

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm creating a service in a docker-compose.yml in the following way:

```
  app:
    build:
      context: <contextDir>
      dockerfile: <dockerfile>
```

I want `app` image to be rebuilt every time the compose goes up.

I know that `docker-compose up --build` rebuilds all the images, but I'm starting the docker-compose.yml from a Maven plugin so I cannot pass that argument (not supported by the plugin)

So, my question is: is there any way to indicate *inside* docker-compose.yml that images should be rebuilt?

Thanks.

Comment: I figured out they have up-build, see the answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I can see in `docker-compose-maven-plugin`, you can make argument.
here the code they made in pom.xml:

```
<pomInclude>up-build/pom.xml</pomInclude>
```

you can do like this:

```
<configuration>
  <buildArgs>
    ...
    <upBuild>true</upBuild>
    ...
  </buildArgs>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Which docker-compose-maven-plugin are you using? I'm using this one: https://github.com/br4chu/docker-compose-maven-plugin

Comment: I found on this one: https://github.com/dkanejs/docker-compose-maven-plugin

Comment: I think it is better than yours

Comment: I tried it but I really need this missing feature: https://github.com/dkanejs/docker-compose-maven-plugin/issues/88#issuecomment-626012086

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it using this [Maven plugin](http://%20github.com/br4chu/docker-compose-maven-plugin) since the author added the [required feature](https://github.com/br4chu/docker-compose-maven-plugin/issues/7).